# Cant Write Values when Reading from Firebase's Firestore. Saying "update is not a function"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read a prize pool I have in my database, than add that prize pool to a users balance. This seems like a pretty simple command to do, but is proving difficult within Firestore and Firebase.

```
        const totalEach = db.collection('prizes').doc('prize2AM');

        totalEach.get().then((choice: any) => {
            let total = choice.data().amount

            let tempUser = db.collection('users', ref => ref.where('id', '==', 'seRCUOAYSbOm8QbG0JI3ssHCMsZ2'));

            tempUser.get().then(userGet => {
              let userBalance = choice.data().amount

              tempUser.update({
                balance: userBalance+=total
              });
            });

        });
```

I am being told within my console that update is not a function. I have also tried doing this with

```
tempUser.update("balance", FieldValue.increment(2));
```

And got the same not a function error happening.

In addition I have tried adding ref in various places in my statements. For example db.ref.collection, but this also gave me an error. Saying that collection was undefined, or that you can not read of update undefined.

Not really sure whats going on here, and how I should go about updating my information. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tempUser` is a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query) object.  As you can see from the linked API documentation, Query doesn't have a method called `update`.  You can only update an individual document referenced by a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) object.  You can NOT "bulk update" the entire results of a query - you will have to execute the query, iterate the results, find the DocumentReference of each [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) (using its `ref` property), and call update() on each one individually.

Comment: Thank you Doug! I appreciate the help. I was way off with what I was thinking the problem was. I was just searching for a specific user so a query wasn't actually necessary, I changed it to a collection.doc and everything is working perfectly. 
I did however have a hard time when going through the docs figuring out how to 
loop through your query and turn the desired items into DocumentReferences. Thankfully there were some good references on stackoverflow, the solution to this was infact quite simple and intuitive but still harder to find than expected.